# How do I delete a shared RawArray in Python to free up memory space

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I´m working with an array of size ****(256**4, dtype=ctypes.c_short)**** which takes **8 GB in memory** as a **multiprocessing.RawArray** object in memory. After i did all calculations, i haven´t found a way to free up that space.The following don´t work:

```py
X = RawArray(ctypes.c_short, 256**4)

del X
```

Is there a special method to delete this kind of object?

I´m working in a Jupyter notebook in Windows with Python 3.7

Comment: I created and deleted an array as you've shown and it deleted.  Are you sure you have no other references to the memory?  Check `sys.getrefcount(X)`.  Using it as an argument to `sys.getrefcount` is a reference, so the answer should be 2 if there are no other references besides `X` and the `getrefcount` argument.

Comment: @Mark inserting `sys.getrefcount(X)` into the end of my code returns 4. `sys.getrefcount(X)` directly after creating the variable returns 2. So that might be a Problem. But creating a RawArray in a fresh notebook and deleting it right after still does not free memory.

Comment: I tested in a Windows console and it freed.  I just tried in Jupyter and it did not, even though it was the only reference.  Restarting the kernel worked.  I don't have an explanation.